# Definition not found for symbol 'QMHSNDPM'

Tags: rpgle

I am following Scott Klement's tutorials on IFS programming with RPGLE. I am facing the below issues. I have added the code snippets as well. Please assist.

```
Ownership of object WITHERRH in QTEMP type *MODULE changed.            
*SRVPGM object QZDMMDTA in library QSOC not found.                     
Definition not found for symbol 'QMHSNDPM'.                            
Definition not found for symbol 'QMHSNDPM'.                            
Program WITHERRH in library ABCLIBL not created.
```

The PR were defined inside this copy source.

```
 /if not defined(ERRNO_H)                                          
D strerror        PR              *   extproc('strerror')          
D  errnum                       10I 0 value                        
 /define ERRNO_H                                                   
 /endif                                                            

 /if defined(ERRNO_LOAD_PROCEDURE)                                 
P die             B                                                
D die             PI              N                                
D  msg                         256A   const                        

D QMHSNDPM        PR                  extproc('QMHSNDPM')          
D  messageId                     7A   const                        
D  qualMsgF                     20A   const                        
D  msgData                     256A   const                        
D  msgDataLen                   10I 0 const                        
D  msgType                      10A   const                  
D  callSktEnt                   10A   const                  
D  callSktCnt                   10I 0 const                  
D  messageKey                    4A                          
D  errorCode                   256A                          

D dsEC            DS                                         
D  dsECBytesP             1      4I 0 inz(%size(dsEC))       
D  dsECBytesA             5      8I 0 inz(0)                 
D  dsECMsgId              9     15                           
D  dsECReserv            16     16                           
D  dsECMsgData           17    256                           
D msgLen          S             10I 0                        
D theKey          S              4A                          

       msgLen = %checkr(msg:' ');                            
       if msgLen < 1;                                        
          return *off;                                         
       endif;                                                  

       callP  QMHSNDPM('CPF9897':'QCPFMSG   *LIBL':msg:msgLen: 
                       '*ESCAPE':'*':3:theKey:dsEC);           
       return *off;                                            
P                 E
```

The main program has QC2LE binding directory added; the 'die' procedure is invoked as below,

```
H dftactgrp(*no) actgrp(*new) bnddir('QC2LE')    

D/copy ABCLIBL/QIFSSRC,IFSIO_H                 
D/copy ABCLIBL/QIFSSRC,ERRNO_H               
.....
if write(fd:%addr(wrdata):%size(wrdata)) < 1; 
   errMsg = %str(strerror(errno));            
   callP close(fd);                           
   callP die('open(): ' + errMsg);            
endif;
```

Comment: QMHSNDPM isn't an extproc(). It's an extpgm().

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user2338816 said QMHSNDPM is a external program not a procedure:

```
D QMHSNDPM        PR                  extpgm('QMHSNDPM')
```

Most APIs are external programs and not procedures. And when they aren't external programs it's easy to see from the documentation.

For example: [Dump Module Variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/apis/QTEDMPMV.htm)

With this API you would bind your program to the QTEDMPV service program and then use extproc to reference the procedure.

```
D DumpVariables   PR                  extproc('QteDumpModuleVariables')
```